# Why can I not get worldclim data (avg temp and prec) for the state which I live at all using R?

Tags: r, statistics, stack, spatial

I'd like to get the average temperature and precipitation for the state of Ceara in Brazil; I made a cropped area on the map as:

[image]

and I used the center lat/lon as `lat=-5.49839` and `lon=-39.32062` I got the caps of latitude and longitude as `latinicial=-7.24614` (minimum latitude), `latfinal=-3.76140` (maximum latitude), `longinicial=-40.38084` (minimum longitude) and `longfinal=-38.77385` (maximum longitude) then I've simulated a uniformly distributed temperature for both latitude and longitude which lies in their maxima and minima.

My code is given as follows:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(dismo)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
d=getData('worldclim',lat=-5.49839,lon=-39.32062,res=0.5,var='bio')
latinicial=-7.24614
latfinal=-3.76140
longinicial=-40.38084
longfinal=-38.77385
latitude=runif(100,latinicial,latfinal)
longitude=runif(100,longinicial,longfinal)
coord=data.frame(latitude,longitude)
points = SpatialPoints(coord, proj4string = d@crs)
d <- d[[c(1,12)]]
names(d)=c("Temp","Prec")
extract(d,points)
```

But when I run it, I got NA values for all rows even though I'm showing you only 4 rows:

[image]

So, I'd like to know what happened to it. Why do I get NA values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the order of longitude and latitude in `coords`. When you put `coords` into `SpatialPoints`, it expects the order to be `longitude` then `latitude`, but you have it reversed. Once you fix that, then it will extract the data correctly. All the code above `coord` works fine. Also, if you are going to run this code multiple times, then I would recommend using `set.seed`. This will allow you to get the same values every time when you run the `runif` statements.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

set.seed(243)
d = getData(
  'worldclim',
  lat = -5.49839,
  lon = -39.32062,
  res = 0.5,
  var = 'bio'
)
latinicial = -7.24614
latfinal = -3.76140
longinicial = -40.38084
longfinal = -38.77385
latitude = runif(100, latinicial, latfinal)
longitude = runif(100, longinicial, longfinal)
coord = data.frame(longitude, latitude)
points = SpatialPoints(coord, proj4string = d@crs)
d <- d[[c(1, 12)]]
names(d) = c("Temp", "Prec")
extract(d, coord)
```

**Output**

```
head()

       Temp Prec
  [1,]  239  655
  [2,]  267  832
  [3,]  256  541
  [4,]  269  740
  [5,]  242  784
  [6,]  233  981
```

Comment: I'm not believing it. I was stucked on it for hours.